# How to use two models from different apps in one template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I want two models from different apps to be rendered in one template. For example in my home page there are list of posts showing post author and post content accordingly. When I will click on author tag I want to show author profile at the top and list of posts by that author bellow. I am using class based view (ListView andd DetailView).
In my 'users app' I have Profile model and in 'blog app' I have Post model.

```
blog/models.py
    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        content = models.TextField()
        date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

users/models.py
    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

users/views.py
    class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Profile

        # to get two model in one page
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()
            return context
my template
    <div class="">
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
    <div class="media">
      <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ object.image.url }}">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="account-heading">{{object.user.username}}</h2>
        <p class="text-secondary">{{object.user.email}}</p>
        <p class="text-secondary">{{object.user.profile.phone}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="">
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">User's Posts</legend>
        <h2 class="account-heading">{{?????}}</h2>
        <p class="text-secondary">{{??????}}</p>
</div>


urls.py
        path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.ProfileDetailView.as_view(), 
              name='profile-detail'),
```

So, my question is how to make queries to get posts from selected/clicked user. User Profile part is working fine. But cannot get data from post model.

Comment: Hi, "how to make queries to get posts from selected/clicked user." - is your question or this - "I want two models from different apps to be rendered in one template" ?

Comment: I want that query to be executed when I select that user in different template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my answer. Thanks to all who tried to help me. 
Problem was in querying. Comment from rohit keshav was a hint to my problem. Following is the code:

```
users/views.py
    class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
        model = Profile

        # to get two model in one page
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['posts']=Post.objects.filter(author=self.object.user)
            return context
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend your User model and add a get_absolute_url() method, which will return a relative or an absolute path to your author foreign key while rendering post.

See the official django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url

```
{% for each in posts %}
<li>{{each.title}} | Written by <a href="{{each.author.get_absolute_url}}">{{each.author}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since v1.7 ([see release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/1.7/)) `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser` no longer defines a `get_absolute_url()` method.

As a consequence you need to create the [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url) method for your User model so that you can use `{{ user.get_aboslute_url}}` in your templates.

This can be done **either through a custom User model** as [dotslash227 suggest in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57697380/1622937), **or by adding the [`ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES) to your settings**, which might be somewhat simpler.

Ether way you then can `{{ user.get_aboslute_url }}` in your template (more like `{{each.author.get_absolute_url}}` in your case).

For the latter case, the settings part might look something like:

```py
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {
    'auth.user': lambda u: "/users/%s/" % u.username,
}
```

**Obviously, in any case, you still need to define a view for this pattern.**

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current user in your `DetailView` class using `self.request.user`

Hence to get a specific user's posts, this is what you might looking for -

`context['posts'] = Posts.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)` since author is a foreign key pointing to the Users model.

**instead of**

`context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()`

This should give you the posts of the current user. Let me know if you need clarification with anything.

Comment: seems to be working. But now problem is it returns posts just from logged in users. for example I am an A user it shows posts from an A user even if I select other users posts. If B user logged in it shows B user's posts for all users

Comment: Are you looking to create a per user filter, irrespective of the currently logged in user?
I assumed that you are trying to display current logged in user posts.

Comment: yes I want to  to create a per user filter, irrespective of the currently logged in user

Comment: thanks Rohit. I've handled my problem. Your answer was a hint. context['posts']=Post.objects.filter(author=self.object.user)